# Leafpad ignoring gtkrc

Tags: debian, gtk

On a fresh install of Debian Wheezy, I have Leafpad 0.8.18.1-3. Following [instructions](http://tarot.freeshell.org/leafpad/.gtkrc-2.0) I created a .gtkrc-2.0 in my home folder and put the commands to change the text area colors. This had no effect.

The problem has been noted [before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82767/how-do-i-change-the-background-colour-of-leafpad-changing-gtkrc-insufficient), but didn't get an answer. I did find mention of someone having it work several years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a Desktop Environment, your `.gtkrc-2.0` may be totally ignored. In Xfce4 for example, you can add rules manually through `xfce4-settings-editor`, under `xsettings -> Gtk`.

You can also try editing the gtkrc file for the Gtk+ theme you are currently using. It is under `/usr/share/themes/THEMENAME/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` or `~/.themes/THEMENAME/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`

Comment: Only IceWM, no DE and no prior .gtkrc-2.0. I put the config info in /usr/share/themes/Default/gtk-2.0-key/gtkrc and then it worked. I deleted .gtkrc-2.0 from home but found it was still needed. Then removed from /usr/.../gtkrc and it still worked. Now Leafpad reads config changes directly from the .gtkrc-2.0 in home directory.